# No such cookbook -- OpsWorks can't find custom cookbook

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I'm trying to figure out the best way to add an nginx server as a proxy for my node.js AWS OpsWorks machines. I have not been able to get it working, as Chef/OpsWorks cannot seem to find the cookbook. Here is my setup: I am using the node.js layer, and have created a git repo for the chef recipes for nginx. I have enabled custom recipes, and I have successfully used a custom HAproxy attributes file from this repo. The structure of the repo is as follows:

```
nginx-custom
 --recipes
 --templates
 --attributes
haproxy
 --attributes
```

The weird thing is that the HAproxy overrides work. The nginx cookbook is basically copy-pasted from the OpsWorks version, with some of my own attributes (Maybe b/c it is a full cookbook is the problem?). So when I try to run the nginx-custom cookbook as part of the setup step (I've added the name of the cookbook to the setup step with the default recipe like 'nginx-custom::default'), I get the "No such cookbook" error. I've tried running it as a standalone command with the sam result. Am I doing something obviously wrong? Should I use Berkshelf for this? Should I make a custom layer instead of trying to modify an existing one? Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you've enabled custom recipes have you configured OPsWorks to go to your GIT repo?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-installingcustom-enable.html

If your GIT repo is on Github for instance you'll have to also authorize Amazon to access your repo using the proper SSH Key.

Also ensure the nginx has all the dependencies it needs in order to run. It might be easier to just put the cookbooks in a tar.gz and upload it to S3 to use.